How can I prevent wx.StaticText from removing consecutive whitespaces in it's input string?
I want to print text on a window such that the text is justified (like in MS-Word). when I input a string to wx.StaticText(panel, label=txt), it completely ignores duplicate spaces and replaces them with one space for each.
How to prevent wx.StaticText from modifying the input text? How can I get justified text using wx.StaticText? is there a way to override this behavior?
p.s. I am aware that I can draw directly on a panel using wx.PaintDC's methods, but it is tedious.
Here is a screenshot of the input string and what I get in the window:


I’m not entirely sure it will make any difference, but did you try with wx.lib.stattext.GenStaticText instead of wx.StaticText?

@Infinity77 I have tried to override the SetLabel function of the class GenStaticText by inheriting from it, but the GenStaticText itself uses SetLabel from it's superclass wx.Control, this does not change the results. I also tried to use wx.Control.SetLabelText, which claims to "Sets the control's label to exactly the given string", but that also did not work.

wx.StaticText does not change the label string, but a monospaced font should be used for the lines of the paragraph to maintain vertical alignment. like so:
font = wx.Font(pointSize=15, family=wx.FONTFAMILY_MODERN,\
               style=wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, weight=wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL,\
               faceName="Courier New")
staticText = wx.StaticText(parentPanel, label=text, style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
staticText.SetFont(font)

